# Showing selected feature in Attribute Table (Show All Records)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table

I have a bunch of records in my attribute table (some of which are duplicates) I can select them individually and click the 'show selected tab' to see them, however it would be much more productive for me if when I selected a data point it would automatically go to it under the 'show all records tab' in the attribute table. This way I could automatically see the duplicates around it (by ordering my attribute data numerically).

As it currently stands when I make the select I have to manually scroll up and down etc to find it in the show all records' tab of the attribute table.

Comment: I do understand your problem, and would find this to be useful as well. When working with a table you can hit CRTL+G, which allows you to enter a row number, and the table will zoom to that row, HOWEVER, this is the row number as currently sorted, so it only corresponds to the FID (or whatever the unique ID field is) when the table is sorted on that field. And since when looking for duplicate records you'll be sorted on a field other than FID, this is not particularly helpful. As far as I know there is no other way to zoom to a selected row in a table.

Comment: Ok thanks - yes seems like such a simple thing, but as of yet no way to do this! :-l

Comment: Have you investigated the Find Identical tool? It creates another table, however, you could join the results back on objectid or something else. Also, if your potential duplicates are selected, you could Calculate a field, then use that field in a Definition Query, to turn all other records off.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way to do what you are requesting.

I have just done a quick search of [ArcGIS Ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com) to see if anyone has asked for it before and could not find an existing idea.

I recommend that you post a new one there.

I imagine the way to describe what you are after is:

> Scroll attribute window to first/next/previous/last **selected** row while showing all (not just selected) records.